# SQL XML find and replace

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

So I'm dealing with a field in a table that contains XML data and from line to line the number of parameters in the XML field will vary (as will the name of the variables).

I need to be able to search a field containing XML for my `<variablename>tminus1</variablename>`
(I did not design the XML structure, I'm just the one who has to work around it) and replace the `<ValueAsString>data here</ValueAsString>` 
with new data that is dynamically generated by a trigger that monitors table changes.

Because of how the XML is setup I've spent days trying to figure this out but I'm at a loss. Can anyone help? The Trigger part is easy it's find the right XML location to replace that I'm having a hard time with.

```
    <Parameters>
<Parameter><VariableID>(1012,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkFormat</VariableName><ListID>(1042,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
<Parameter><VariableID>(2226,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkProofType</VariableName><ListID>(1045,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
<Parameter><VariableID>(2224,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkReceivedVia</VariableName><ListID>(1043,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
<Parameter><VariableID>(2225,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkReturnVia</VariableName><ListID>(1044,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
<Parameter><VariableID>(10306,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus1</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/12/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter>
<Parameter><VariableID>(10308,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus3</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/10/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter>
<Parameter><VariableID>(10307,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus2</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/11/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One- or Two-step replacement

As others pointed out, there is a problem, if you want to replace the text value of a node given as `<ValueAsString />`. The `.modify(N'replace value of...` demands for a `/text()` at the end as target for the replacment, but there isn't... The simple way will work for the given case, but will not work if in the `<Parameter>` you want to change the target node is empty as it is in `VariableName="ArtworkReturnVia"`:

```
DECLARE @SearchFor NVARCHAR(100)='tminus1';
DECLARE @SetValue NVARCHAR(100)='NewData';

UPDATE @tbl SET XmlColumn.modify(N'replace value of (/Parameters/Parameter[VariableName=sql:variable("@SearchFor")]/ValueAsString)[1]/text()[1]
                                   with sql:variable("@SetValue")')
```

One straight approach was to delete this element in any case and do an insert:

```
UPDATE @tbl SET XmlColumn.modify(N'delete (/Parameters/Parameter[VariableName=sql:variable("@SearchFor")]/ValueAsString)[1]')
UPDATE @tbl SET XmlColumn.modify(N'insert <ValueAsString>{sql:variable("@SetValue")}</ValueAsString> into (/Parameters/Parameter[VariableName=sql:variable("@SearchFor")])[1]')
```

### One more approach: **Full FLWOR**

```
UPDATE @tbl SET XmlColumn=XmlColumn.query
('<Parameters>
  {
    for $p in /Parameters/Parameter
    return <Parameter>
    {
    if($p/*/text()=sql:variable("@SearchFor")) then
            for $nd in $p/*
            return
            if(local-name($nd)="ValueAsString") then
                    <ValueAsString>{sql:variable("@SetValue")}</ValueAsString>
            else
                    $nd
    else $p
    }
    </Parameter>
  }
</Parameters>
');
```

### Another one: **Semi FLWOR**

```
WITH Prms AS
(
    SELECT ID --needs an ID here
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NodeOrder
          ,p.query('.') AS prm
    FROM @tbl 
    CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/Parameters/Parameter') AS A(p)
)
UPDATE tbl SET XmlColumn=
(
SELECT CASE WHEN prm.value('(/Parameter/VariableName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')=@SearchFor 
            THEN prm.query('<Parameter>
                            {
                            for $nd in /Parameter/*
                            return
                                if(local-name($nd)="ValueAsString") then
                                    <ValueAsString>{sql:variable("@SetValue")}</ValueAsString>
                                else
                                    $nd
                            }
                            </Parameter>
                           ')
            ELSE prm END
FROM Prms
WHERE Prms.ID=tbl.ID
ORDER BY Prms.NodeOrder
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Parameters')
)
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

Comment: Much better, Never have to worry about structural changes to the data.

Comment: @Keith, just saw, that the *full-FLWOR* approach could be simplified. No need for the loop to return the unchanged parameters... See edited version

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into XML DML, specifically the [replace value of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx) command. XML DML allows for inline modification of XML data, via the `.modify()` XML function, without needing to convert it to `NVARCHAR` and then back to `XML`. You would use that along with one, or both, of the following (depending on where you are getting the replacement values from):

- [sql:column()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx)
- [sql:variable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx)

I worked up the following example, using @JohnCappelletti's example code as the basis, but the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE` is different. The `/Parameters/Parameter[//VariableName[1]=sql:variable("@KeyNode")]/ValueAsString/text()` XQuery says to get the "/Parameters/Parameter" element in which the "VariableName" element name contains the string found in the "@KeyNode" variable, then grab the text of the "ValueAsString" child element. That will get replaced with the value from the "@NewValue" variable.

The only thing I haven't been able to get working is the replacement of an empty element (i.e. the `<ValueAsString />` elements). I'm sure there is a way, but I just don't meddle with this stuff enough to know the nuances.

```sql
DECLARE @KeyNode  NVARCHAR(100) = N'tminus1';
DECLARE @NewValue NVARCHAR(100) = N'data here';

DECLARE @YourTable TABLE ([ID] INT, [XMLData] XML);
INSERT INTO @YourTable ([ID], [XMLData]) VALUES 
(1, N'<Parameters>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(1012,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkFormat</VariableName><ListID>(1042,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(2226,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkProofType</VariableName><ListID>(1045,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(2224,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkReceivedVia</VariableName><ListID>(1043,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(2225,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkReturnVia</VariableName><ListID>(1044,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(10306,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus1</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/12/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(10308,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus3</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/10/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter>
    <Parameter><VariableID>(10307,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus2</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/11/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter>
</Parameters>');

UPDATE tmp
SET    [XMLData].modify(N'
  replace value of 
  (/Parameters/Parameter[//VariableName[1]=sql:variable("@KeyNode")]/ValueAsString/text())[1]
  with             sql:variable("@NewValue")')
FROM   @YourTable tmp
WHERE  tmp.[ID] = 1;

SELECT * FROM @YourTable;
```

Please note: `XML` data in SQL Server is always encoded as UTF-16 (Little Endian), which is the same as `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `NTEXT` (but don't use `NTEXT`), so it is best to use `NVARCHAR` for string data containing XML, and remember to prefix literals with a capital-`N`.

Comment: If you work up an example, please ping me.  I'd like to see how it should be done.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I have updated my answer with a working example. Only thing I can't get working is the replacement of empty `<ValueAsString>` elements. Enjoy :)

Comment: I do not know a way either, to replace the `/text()` of an element given as `<element />`. On might use two steps. One to delete this element and second to insert it with the new value instead of the unsure replacement. Or use `FLWOR`... +1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation with XML data deserves extreme caution.

Consider the following **(keeping in mind this is my lizard brain approach)**

```
Declare @KeyNode  varchar(100)='tminus1'
Declare @NewValue varchar(100)='data here'

Declare @YourTable table (ID int,XMLData xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'<Parameters><Parameter><VariableID>(1012,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkFormat</VariableName><ListID>(1042,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter><Parameter><VariableID>(2226,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkProofType</VariableName><ListID>(1045,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter><Parameter><VariableID>(2224,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkReceivedVia</VariableName><ListID>(1043,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter><Parameter><VariableID>(2225,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>ArtworkReturnVia</VariableName><ListID>(1044,1601)</ListID><ListValue>0</ListValue><ValueAsString /></Parameter><Parameter><VariableID>(10306,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus1</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/12/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter><Parameter><VariableID>(10308,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus3</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/10/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter><Parameter><VariableID>(10307,14505)</VariableID><VariableName>tminus2</VariableName><ValueAsString>10/11/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString></Parameter></Parameters>')

Update @YourTable 
Set XMLData = (Select (Select U.VariableID
                             ,U.VariableName
                             ,U.ListID
                             ,U.ListValue
                             ,ValueAsString = case when U.VariableName=@KeyNode then @NewValue else  U.ValueAsString end
                         From ( Select VariableID   = B.value('VariableID[1]'   ,'varchar(max)') 
                                      ,VariableName = B.value('VariableName[1]' ,'varchar(max)') 
                                      ,ListID       = B.value('ListID[1]'       ,'varchar(max)') 
                                      ,ListValue    = B.value('ListValue[1]'    ,'varchar(max)') 
                                      ,ValueAsString= B.value('ValueAsString[1]','varchar(max)') 
                                 From  XMLData.nodes('/Parameters') AS A (Lvl1)
                                 Cross Apply A.Lvl1.nodes('Parameter')AS B(B)
                              ) U
                         For XML Path('Parameter'),Type
                     ) For XML Path ('Parameters'),Type
              )    
 From @YourTable

Select * from @YourTable
```

Update XML is

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(1012,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>ArtworkFormat</VariableName>
    <ListID>(1042,1601)</ListID>
    <ListValue>0</ListValue>
    <ValueAsString></ValueAsString>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(2226,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>ArtworkProofType</VariableName>
    <ListID>(1045,1601)</ListID>
    <ListValue>0</ListValue>
    <ValueAsString></ValueAsString>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(2224,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>ArtworkReceivedVia</VariableName>
    <ListID>(1043,1601)</ListID>
    <ListValue>0</ListValue>
    <ValueAsString></ValueAsString>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(2225,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>ArtworkReturnVia</VariableName>
    <ListID>(1044,1601)</ListID>
    <ListValue>0</ListValue>
    <ValueAsString></ValueAsString>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(10306,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>tminus1</VariableName>                --<< Key Value
    <ValueAsString>data here</ValueAsString>            --<< Updated Value
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(10308,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>tminus3</VariableName>
    <ValueAsString>10/10/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <VariableID>(10307,14505)</VariableID>
    <VariableName>tminus2</VariableName>
    <ValueAsString>10/11/2016 4:00 PM</ValueAsString>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

Comment: I like this, +1, just two thoughts: This works only in case you know all child elements in advance (today and in future) and secondly: I've come to read from xml via `.value()` using `nvarchar(max)` to avoid not needed conversions... (XML is unicode as you surely know...). Did so myself long enough :-) I posted one answer with `FLWOR`. I like this quite exotic "language" :-)